# Spam Complaints from Gmail

Tags: marketing-cloud, data-views, email-tracking

I am surprised to find zero complaints record from "gmail.com". This is from both Spam Complaints Over Time report and Complaints Data View.

I also tried sending a test email and marking it as spam in Gmail, but Complaints Data View has not returned anything record for the same Subkey or JobId. This leads me to think Marketing Cloud isn't capable for recording spam complaints from Gmail.

Does anyone know for sure if Marketing Cloud does capture complaints from Gmail?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google has its own FBL

[GMail Feedback Loop and Marketing Cloud sending](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000380559&type=1)

> Google has a mechanism that they call the “Gmail Feedback Loop.” However, it does not work in same manner as other ISP feedback loops . It provides aggregate, high-level reputation-related statistics relating to a given registered domain name. It provides no mechanism for unsubscribing subscribers who complain, nor does it allow a sender to identify specific sends that may be most problematic.

Comment: Thanks for providing this info @EazyE